# isinstance python return different values

Tags: python, inheritance, isinstance

I am a bit lost about how `isinstance()` works in Python. I have used the function before, and the behavior was quite clear, until now.

A bit of context. I have a class `Classifier` which has a method `set_kernel` that can take a string or a Kernel as the parameter. I am creating from the main function an object of the Kernel type called `k`. When I use `isinstance(k, Kernel)` the answer is `True`. However, if I pass `k` as parameter to the classifier, and then I do the same check inside the function, it returns `False`.

Any clue about what is going on here? I attach some code snippet to make it clearer:

```
class Kernel(object):
    pass

class Gaussian(Kernel):
    pass

class Classifier():
    def set_kernel(kernel, *args):
        print isinstance(kernel, Kernel) # This prints False


k = Gaussian() # This is a son of Kernel
print isinstance(k, Kernel) # This prints True

c = Classifier()
c.set_kernel(k) # This prints False, check above
```

Thanks!

Edit 1: I have improved the coded and cleaned all the things that are not related with the problem itself.

Comment: Note that you can use a more trivial example (such as a `str` instead of a `sl_kernal`) to demonstrate this behavior.

Comment: Your posted code has syntactical errors and wouldn't compile. Please post actually runnable code that actually demonstrates the problem when run.

Comment: Edited correcting the syntactic errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `set_kernel` function is **not** a `staticmethod` the first argument is the instance if you call this function on an instance. See for example:

```
class Classifier():
    def set_kernel(kernel, *args):
        print(kernel)
        print(isinstance(kernel, int))


>>> k = 10
>>> print(k)
10
>>> print(isinstance(k, int))
True

>>> c = Classifier()
>>> c.set_kernel(k)
<__main__.Classifier object at 0x0000020FABD0FDA0>
False
```

If you however make it a `staticmethod` it "works":

```
class Classifier():
    @staticmethod
    def set_kernel(kernel, *args):
        print(kernel)
        print(isinstance(kernel, int))

>>> k = 10
>>> print(k)
10
>>> print(isinstance(k, int))
True

>>> c = Classifier()
>>> c.set_kernel(k)
10
True
```

or if you don't want it to be static insert another argument for the instance, typically called "self" in the parameter list:

```
class Classifier():
    def set_kernel(self, kernel, *args):
        print(kernel)
        print(isinstance(kernel, int))
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `self` argument:

```
class Classifier():
    def set_kernel(kernel, *args):
        print isinstance(kernel, Kernel)
```

That means that `kernel` isn't the kernel. As the first positional argument, `kernel` takes the role of `self`, so it's actually the classifier. The kernel you passed to the method ends up as the first element of `args`.

Comment: I thought "self" was a language keyword to refers to the object but that was not related to the position in the arguments. You are right, thank you.

Comment: that it's named "self" is just convention. Python always passes it as first positional argument (if it's called on an instance) no matter what it's called.